# How to recover a lost password in MySQL 5.7.11? (for Windows)

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7, password

I am running MySQL 5.7.11 on Windows 10

I am unable to login to root through the command line client since I lost my password.

How do I change/reset the old password?

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed MySQL as a service, you need the following:

STEP 01

Open Windows Command Line as Administrator and run

```
C:\> net stop mysql
```

STEP 02

Add this to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL 5.7\my.ini` under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

STEP 03

```
C:\> net start mysql
C:\> mysql
```

You should be logged into mysql

STEP 04

Suppose you want root@localhost's password to be `hello`, run this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('hello') where user='root' and host='localhost';
exit
```

STEP 05

```
C:\> net stop mysql
```

STEP 06

Remove the `skip-grant-tables` option from the `my.ini`

STEP 07

```
C:\> net start mysql
```

STEP 08

```
C:\> mysql -uroot -p
```

This should prompt you for the password. Enter new password and you should be in.

## ALTERNATIVE

Instead of creating `my.ini`, do the following after you have shutdown MySQL

```
C:\> cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
C:\> start mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables
C:\> mysql
```

You should now be inside mysql without a password. Next run this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('hello') where user='root' and host='localhost';
exit
```

Back at the command line, shutdown mysql like this:

```
C:\> mysqladmin shutdown
```

Now, you start MySQL57 Service back up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42131/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-shubham-deshmukh).